# Invalid Object Name: Beginner using the AdventureWords db from a class

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I'm trying to learn some C#.net.  I'm just trying to expose the AdventureWorks database included in my C# class via a web interface.  Here's the setup:

I've got a `DropDownList` in on my ASPX page with an id of `tableNameDropDown`.  It gets populated on `Page_Load` like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conn.Open();

        String table_names_sql = "select Name from sysobjects where type='u' ORDER BY name";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(table_names_sql, conn);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {

            tableNameDropDown.Items.Add(reader[0].ToString());
        }

        conn.Close();

        tableNameDropDown.AutoPostBack = true;
    }
```

And that works just fine, I get a nice long list of the tables in the DB.  When someone selects a table from the list, I want to display that table in a `GridView` control with an id of `grid`.  This is what I've got:

```
protected void tableNameDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

        String tableName = columnNameDropDown.SelectedItem.ToString();
        String table_sql = String.Format("SELECT * FROM {0};", tableName);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(table_sql, conn);
        adapter.Fill(dataSet, tableName);

        grid.DataSource = dataSet;
        grid.DataMember = tableName;
    }
```

When I debug the page, I get an error on the `adapter.Fill(dataSet, tableName);` line: SqlException: Inlvalid object name '{tableName}'.

The tables in the DB are the following:

```
dbo.AWBuildVersion
.... more dbo. tables

HumanResources.Department
HumanResources.Employee
.... more HumanResources tables

Person.Address
Person.AddressType
.... more Person tables

... Other prefixes are "Pdoduction, Purchasing, Sales"
```

There are probably ~50+ tables, and I get all their names (without the prefixes) into my DropDownList no problem, but I can't seem to query them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already answered yourself: you need to use also the prefix in the select statement you're executing, like

```
Select * From Person.Address
```

Beside that you should not use the sysobject tables, from SQL Server 2005 you have system views that helps you, so you can write a better statement to select tables:

```
select * From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

Check also [this article](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3508881/SQL-Server-2005-System-Tables-and-Views.htm).

Regards
Massimo

Comment: Is there a way to programmatically get the table prefix along with the table in my DropDownList?  Then I'd be able to turn around and use it in the query.